# Spring-Jersey-Jackson-JSON: Array element wrapped by index

Tags: spring, jersey, jsonp, jackson, resty-gwt

I'm writing a restful service using Jersey and Jackson for de/serialization.  I'm using Spring to for dependency injection, I'm also using `com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet` (not using mvc).  I'm using RestyGWT on the client side.  I'm returning an array of objects from my service, my client is complaining that it is not a valid JSON document.  Here is what the service is returning:

```
   {
    "0": {
        "type": "AQUISITION_DT",
        "value": "2013-2-1",
        "stats": {
            "total": 91,
            "used": 4
        }
    },
    "1": {
        "type": "AQUISITION_DT",
        "value": "2013-1-1",
        "stats": {
            "total": 24,
            "used": 13
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure, but I think the problem is that each element is wrapped by its index.  Is there a way I can instruct Jersey or Jackson to unwrap the array elements?  Please let me know if I need provide more info.

In the code I'm sending the result back as a JSONWithPadding Object like so: `return new JSONWithPadding(array, callback);`

btw, I've already configured jersey in my `web.xml` to use POJO Mapping:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

**UPDATE**
I did a test with curl from the terminal and the string that is returned looks correct (I've removed the callback enclosure):

```
 {
    {
        "type": "AQUISITION_DT",
        "value": "2013-2-1",
        "stats": {
            "total": 91,
            "used": 4
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "AQUISITION_DT",
        "value": "2013-1-1",
        "stats": {
            "total": 24,
            "used": 13
        }
    }
}
```

The string that I originally posted is being reported by restyGWT.  Sorry for the confusing post, I'm not sure why restyGwt is complaining...

Thanks!

Comment: How do you return JSON in code?

Comment: 1) As said by Willy below you should have square brackets 2) you should paste your client side code if you want us to help you. In your restService interface getting your array what is the type in your callback ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I was able to get around this problem was to wrap the result in an object.  Originally I was returning an array (`MyObject[]`).  Now I'm returning `MyObjectListing:`

```
public class MyObjectListing {
   MyObject[] objects;
   ...
   //getters/setters, etc.
}
```

returning MyObjectListing solves the problem...I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return an array of objects, the json format should be like below

```
[
   {
      "type":"AQUISITION_DT",
      "value":"2013-2-1",
      "stats":{
         "total":91,
         "used":4
      }
   },
   {
      "type":"AQUISITION_DT",
      "value":"2013-1-1",
      "stats":{
         "total":24,
         "used":13
      }
   }
]
```

You can easily return an array in your resource method like below

```
@Path("/test")
@GET        
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Test[] haha(){
    Test[] arr = new Test[3]; 
    arr[0] = new Test();
    arr[1] = new Test();
    arr[2] = new Test();
    return arr;
}
```

Where Test class is like below

```
public class Test {
    public String type="AQUISITION_DT"; 
    public String value = "2013-2-1";
    public Stats stats = new Stats();
}

public class Stats {
    public int total = 10;
    public int used = 13;
}
```